# Блокировка редактируемых вопросов

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено

Сегодня хотел помочь человеку и перевёл вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/553165. Пока писал перевод (вопрос был в режиме редактирования) - тему заблокировали.

Можно ли и нужно ли сделать возможность устанавливать блокировку возможности блокировать тему во время её редактирования?

Как более культурный подход - можно вывести мини-чат с редактирующим в духе "Я собираюсь заблокировать этот вопрос. Есть возражения?". Если в ответ тишина - то ок - блокируем вопрос. Если же редактирующий просит пару минут на завершение правки - можно предоставить ему это время. Так и вопрос можно улучшить и задавшим вопрос - получить ответ.

Comment: редактирующий просит пару минут на завершение правки ... и правка оказывается фиксом форматирования :)

Comment: вопрос, который вы пытались перевести - не стоило переводить. и не стоило минусовать (на момент переноса на него прилетело уже 3 минуса). если вы видите вопрос, заданный на нормальном английском - то стоит проголосовать за его закрытие, указав в качестве причины необходимость переноса на enSO. перевод вопроса на русский в этом случае ничем автору не поможет - т.к. автор, скорее всего, просто ошибся сайтом.

Comment: Или полным переводом статьи. Правда неприятно - потратить время на что-то нужное/важное и увидеть "статья заблокирована, правки запрещены" посреди процесса?

Comment: Ок. Если его перенесли - претензий нет. Спасибо.

Comment: @DimXenon На сколько я знаю, перед отправкой внесенных изменений вы должны видеть специальное сообщение, если кто–либо сохранил другую правку во время пока вы редактировали исходное сообщение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полностью согласен с ответом (в комментарии) [@PashaPash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177221/pashapash)

> вопрос, который вы пытались перевести - не стоило переводить. и не стоило минусовать (на момент переноса на него прилетело уже 3 минуса). если вы видите вопрос, заданный на нормальном английском - то стоит проголосовать за его закрытие, указав в качестве причины необходимость переноса на enSO. перевод вопроса на русский в этом случае ничем автору не поможет - т.к. автор, скорее всего, просто ошибся сайтом.

Лишь дополню тем, что если исходный вопрос показался вам интересным и вы перевели его, вы можете опубликовать его самостоятельно. Если вы не ассоциируете себя с этим вопросом (хотите показать, что он не ваш), пожалуйста, [сделайте вопрос общим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki). Так же, вы можете упомянуть меня в чате, чтобы я отменил авторство. В этом случае, вопрос будет значиться заданным анонимно.